# libarchive - Extract to specified directory

Tags: c++, archive

I have a tar file I want to extract with libarchive to a specific directory. How can I make libarchive extract into to any directory I want? At the moment it *always* extracts into my program's working directory. I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496001/libarchive-to-extract-to-a-specified-folder) but all this does is change the location of an archive entry within the archive, i.e. it still extracts into my program's working directory just at a different sub-directory.

Comment: The only way I can get it to extract where I want to is by changing the working directory of my program to my desired directory, doing the extract work with libarchive, and then changing it back. This is dirty though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the libarchive discussion boards:

"It depends, of course, on the archive being extracted.

Typically, you would chdir()  to the directory where you want the output to go, then use code similar to that in the Wiki Examples page:

[A Complete Extractor Example](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/Examples#wiki-A_Complete_Extractor)

or in the untar.c sample program:

[untar Example](https://web.archive.org/web/20130309042757/http://libarchive.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/untar.c)

Of course, if the tar file you're extracting has
interesting filenames (such as "c:\someotherdirectory"),
then you'll need to play with the filenames as you extract.

Note that the examples all use archive_read_next_header()
to get an entry object from the input archive describing
the next entry; you are then free to edit that entry description
in any way you wish -- in particular, you can change the
name, owner, or permissions -- before calling
archive_write_header() to recreate the entry on
disk.

The Examples page in the Wiki above is probably the
best place to start."

Answer (score 29):

I resolved this issue next way:
(insert this code before calling 'archive_write_header' function)

```
    const char* currentFile = archive_entry_pathname(archiveEntry);
    const std::string fullOutputPath = destination + currentFile;
    archive_entry_set_pathname(archiveEntry, fullOutputPath.c_str());
```

where `destination` is output path. 
And it works.

Answer (score 0):

A longer C version of Alex's answer. To extract files to a `temp_dir`, use `archive_entry_pathname()` and `archive_entry_set_pathname()` to re-write each entry::

```
char* dest_file;

for (;;) {
    r = archive_read_next_header(a, &entry);
    if (r == ARCHIVE_EOF)
      break;
    if (r < ARCHIVE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", archive_error_string(a));
    if (r < ARCHIVE_WARN)
      return NULL;

    asprintf(&dest_file, "%s/%s", temp_dir, archive_entry_pathname(entry));
    archive_entry_set_pathname(entry, dest_file);
    // printf(" writing %s\n", dest_file);

    r = archive_write_header(ext, entry);
    if (r < ARCHIVE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", archive_error_string(ext));
    else if (archive_entry_size(entry) > 0) {
      r = copy_data(a, ext);
      if (r < ARCHIVE_OK)
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", archive_error_string(ext));
      if (r < ARCHIVE_WARN)
        exit(1);
    }
    r = archive_write_finish_entry(ext);
    if (r < ARCHIVE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", archive_error_string(ext));
    if (r < ARCHIVE_WARN)
      return NULL;

    free(dest_file);
}
```