# How do you extract an archive to a specific location with libarchive?

Tags: c++, file, archive

I've got a C++ program that uses libarchive to extract archives. It extracts them in the current working directory of the program. But I need it to extract them into a directory specified by the user. Changing the working directory is undesirable for various reasons, and the documentation of libarchive doesn't appear to contain anything on file paths when writing to disk. Can it be done?

The code in the first reply to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496001/libarchive-to-extract-to-a-specified-folder) would modify the archive being extracted, which I do not want to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Libarchive to extract to a specified folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496001/libarchive-to-extract-to-a-specified-folder)

Comment: @AlexM. the code in the relevant reply to that question would modify the archive being extracted which I don't want.